# How can you fix a site with duplicate (mirrored) document libraries?

Tags: 2007, site-collection

I have a site with 2 document libraries that are identical. When I change one the other is updated. When I add a document to one it is added to the other. This site collection was created from a site that I exported and imported into the root of a blank site collection.

Comment: Closed on behalf of @Bob since it is unlikely this will ever be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Using SharePoint Manager, do they show up as the two different doc libraries or do you just have two different links going to the same doc library?  Do they have different guids or the same guid?  Do they have different urls?

Comment: One problem with this, besides a mirror copy, was that when you tried to upload multiple documents an error was generated. I tried to save the list as a template and recreate it, but it had the same flaw except it wasn't mirrored. I never got to check what you suggested because I ended up creating a new doc lib and moved the files over. The users were in a hurry and that was the only thing I could think to do. It worked, but I lost all the original Creator names. If I were to have been able to look at them and determine they were the same(GUIDS, etc), what could I have done differently?

Comment: I might would have tried using the stsadm extensions (see http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2007/09/importexportcopy-lists.html) to export and import the list or individual list items.  This would have kept the document metadata (like creator).

Comment: I've heard of those, but I need to get the farm up to SP2 so I can use them. I'm planning on doing that soon. Thanks.